# How to Shim System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentiy in .NET461?

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes, windows-identity

**Summary**

I have opened a .NET461 solution in VisualStudio 2017 and 2019 and tried to compile it. The build is complaining that the `ShimWindowsIdentity` cannot be found in the corresponding Test project. There is no problem with the build  and especially the `ShimWindowsIdentity`in Visual Studio 2015.

**Goal**

I need to shim the constructor of the `WindowsIdentity` to unit test a function. I know there are possibilities to wrap the `WindowsIdentity`, but this require code changes (refactoring) I want to avoid for now.

**Tried so far**

I have tried and checked the following to get the shims for `WindowsIdentity` working in VS 2017/2019:

- Deleted the fakes assemblies and build them from scratch
- Disabled stub generation and explicitly added the stubs and shims needed for `mscorlib.fakes`
- Checked the `TargetFrameworkVersion` `v4.6.1` in the project and Test project

**mscorlib.fakes**

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
 <Assembly Name="mscorlib" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
 <StubGeneration>
   <Clear />
   <Add FullName="System.IO.Stream!"/>
 </StubGeneration>
 <ShimGeneration>
   <Clear/>
   <Add FullName="System.Security.Principal"/>
   <Add FullName="System.DateTime!"/>
   <Add FullName="System.IO.Stream!"/>
 </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

**Expected**

The shims for `WindowsIdentiy` are generated.

**Actual**

I see in the `mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes.messages` the following warning: `Cannot generate shim for System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity: type is not supported because it is not available or changed between versions.`

Answer (score 0):

Had some fun time trying to fake HttpRequest.LogonUserIdentity

1. According to this 
   https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/35053/ms-fakes-is-unable-to-generate-stubs-for-types-inc.html
   you have to target 4.6.2 or the latest installed .net framework version. Give it a try
2. I personally was unable to generate shims for this particular class in my environment (with .net 4.8). I tried targeting 461,462,48. With the 4.8 version I end up with another message :
   Cannot generate shim for System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity+d__95: type is not supported because of internal limitations.

For me it doesn't make any sense to target other versions than my web app is built in (4.6.1) so I just gave up and faked HttpRequestBase class with fake wrapper and overrided httpRequest.LogonUserIdenity returning what I need.